# eclipse window not opened when i am trying to click eclipse.exe

Tags: eclipse

When i am trying to open eclipse exe file , window is not opened , why this is happened , previously it is working fine but today it is not opened any changes i need to do?it will help full if any one gave quick fix .

thanks
Ramana

Comment: I think it is java issue, just now i checked the java using javac and java commands in command prompt(windows) , when i execute "java" command it will gives thefollowing error(Error occurred during initialization of VM,
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object) is there any way to rectify the error or i reinstalled java ??

Answer (score 3):

(The [OP ramana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816815/ramana) solved it by uninstalling and re-installing Java, but below is another potential cause)

Check if your `PATH` hasn't changed somehow: see [Java Tips: “Adventure” in resolving the Java error “Error occurred during initialization of VM”](http://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/java-tips-adventure-in-resolving-the-java-error-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm/)

> Running Java.exe produce error in other directories (since the SDK’s bin is added to path.)

[image]

> **However running in it’s bin directory, it runs fine.**

[image]

---

In the case of the ips mentioned before, the issue was:

> The good news is that it is nothing supernatural or magical image but the bad news is that the Windows directory is the “protagonist” image.
>   From file search, it can be concluded that **somehow certain mischievous program is copying some crucial java files into Windows directory which are stored in path**, and so unless the java’s bin is the foremost in the path, one will bound to get the error.
>
> The error occurs because `java.exe` or other Java executable expect some support files and directories to be found but obviously could not find it in Windows directory.
>   Running the `java.exe` in its bin directory will not produce error because Windows will use  the current directory to which the file is run first before searching for it in the path.

[image]

That might not be the case for you, but that could still be related to a `PATH` issue.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply's, i checked path in environment variables it's valid path only, i didn't get how the error came , i think is jdk issue, i uninstalled java and installed, now the problem solved.

Comment: @ramana: excellent. I have added your solution on top of my answer for more visibility.